# Groups with finitely many roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated infinite group and suppose that $g \in G$ is of infinite order. We say that $x \in G$ is a primitive root of $g$ (denote $x \in \sqrt[G]{g}$) in $G$ if $x^n = g$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is maximal possible.

Is there some condition on $G$ to ensure that primitive root (not necessarily unique) exist for every $g \in G$?
I guess different wording would be for which groups does the equation $x^n = g$ have solution only for finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: "Maximal possible" . This may not be bound at all. For example, for any involution $\;x\in G\;,\;\;x^2=1\;$ , but clearly also $\;x^{2n}=1\;$ for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ .

Comment: I meant for elements of infinite order, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed several important (and rich) classes of groups which satisfy this condition, drawn from the field of geometric group theory.

1. [hyperbolic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_group) (including fundamental groups of compact hyperbolic manifolds)
2. [$\text{CAT}(0)$-groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAT%28k%29_group) (including fundamental groups of compact Riemannian manifolds having sectional curvatures $\le 0$)
3. [automatic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_group)

In each of these cases, there is a certain amount of topology/geometry behind the proof that each element has a primitive root.

Here is a brief example of such a proof. Suppose $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold of sectional curvature $\le 0$ (for example a flat torus with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, or a closed hyperbolic surface of genus $\ge 2$). Every element of $\pi_1(M)$ has a "length" which can be thought of either as the translation length of that element under the deck transformation action on the universal covering space, or as the length of a closed geodesic loop to which a based loop representing that element is freely homotopic. There are two geometric properties of "length", proved using the curvature hypothesis, from which it follows that primitive roots exist:

- There is a constant $L$ such that $0 < L \le \text{length}(g)$ for all $g \in \pi_1(M)$
- $\text{length}(g^n) = n \cdot \text{length}(g)$ for all $g \in \pi_1(M)$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks Lee. However, I was hoping for something slightly more algebraic (or combinatorial) and less geometric. If I understand it correctly, primitive root of $g \in G$ exists if $\langle g \rangle$ is not-distorted (quasi-isometrically embedded) in $G$ with respect to word-lenght metric in $G$. That is why in $BS(1,m) = \langle a,b \mid bab^{-1}=a^m\rangle$ (with $m \geq 2$) the primitive root does not exist for $a$ as $a = (b^{-k}ab^k)^{m^k}$.
So I guess there is no useful sufficient and necessary condition?